# i have the kml and csv file and want to load file in the React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am converting the kml file into the json format and then i am loading in to the google Map but its not working yet. is there any other way to load the file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [react-native-geojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geojson) library? I able to load my local geojson and display it.

For now, I don't see any support for KML with react native maps. [issue #967](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/967)

Comment: Please don't just post a link to a resource. Code snippets and explanations are always helpful